# How do I edit the startup items of an offline system?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a live-USB method to edit the internals (registry, system settings, et cetera) of an offline Windows system? I do freelance computer repair, and when people are asking me to "clean up" their machine, I am often waiting ages for their machine to boot (HDDs, ugh, bloat, ugh). What is the easiest way around this on Windows 10? I cannot clean boot straight from startup, to my knowledge.

Comment: Have you tried Hiren boot disk, using portable XP and then accessing C: drive assuming thats where windows is installed